# Clear or delete 2nd column in csv with python

Tags: python, csv

I have the following code (attempt) at clearing the 2nd column of data in my csv:

```
    def del_col(in_path):
    # read file into memory
        file_obj = open(in_path, 'rb')
        reader = csv.reader(file_obj, delimiter='\t')


# delete the status column here:



# Now write csv back to same file: 

        # write data to file
        file_obj = open(in_path, 'rb')
        writer = csv.writer(file_obj)
        writer.writerows(data)
        file_obj.close()
```

I'm not sure if or how to clear this column. Should I read down the data row-wise and clear the 2nd entry per each row? Or is there a more simplistic way to simply clear the 2nd column at once?

Here is a 2nd attempt:

```
def del_col(in_path):
    # read file into memory
    file_obj = open(in_path, 'rb')
    reader = csv.reader(file_obj, delimiter='\t')
    data = []
    for row in reader:

    # delete the status column here:

        vals = [x[:1] + x[2:] for x in reader]
        print vals
        file_obj.close()

    print 'Delete the 2nd Column (Lead Status?)'
    conf = raw_input('delete these leads? (Y|N): ').upper()[0]

    if conf == 'Y':
        # write data to file
        file_obj = open(in_path, 'wb')
        writer = csv.writer(file_obj)
        writer.writerows(data)
        file_obj.close()
```

Comment: Use my code below and not the extra `for row in reader` loop. The `vals = ` line is a one-line version of a `for` loop that works its way through each row in reader, so your `for row` line will mess things up. I edited my answer to use the name `row` instead of `x` to avoid confusion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just read into a list while omitting the second column:

```
def del_col(in_path):
    # read file into memory
    file_obj = open(in_path, 'rb')
    readfile = csv.reader(file_obj, delimiter='\t')

    # delete the status column here:

    vals = [row[:1] + row[2:] for row in readfile]
    print vals
    file_obj.close()  # if you are going to use the same file name, close and re-open

    # Now write csv to new file: 
    # write data to file
    out_path = in_path + "_out.dat"
    out_obj = open(out_path, 'w')
    writefile = csv.writer(out_obj, delimiter='\t')
    writefile.writerows(vals)
    out_obj.close()
```

Other thoughts: Don't write to the same file that you are reading from. (In this case, I generated a new name based on the old name.) You needed to open the destination file with `'w'` instead of `'r'` and also add the delimiter to the `csv.writer()`...

Comment: Can you take a look at my above edited code? I utilized you middle code section with the layout I've been using in other function, but can't get it to run.

Comment: Sorry 'bout that. Are you using tabs or spaces in your editor? There might have been some mixture of white-space formatting in there. Try copying again (I edited), or delete all the leading white space around those lines that are generating the error and re-insert them, or Show Invisibles in your editor and make sure it is consistent.

Comment: Hmmm... I didn't get an error but the 2nd column is still there. would vals = [x[:0] for x in reader work if I only want to preserve the 1st column?

Comment: Make sure that you also changed the `writer.writerows(vals)` line. I changed it (to `vals`) to print the new variable instead of the one in your original code.

Comment: If you only want to preserve the first column, you would just say `vals = [x[0] for x in reader]` (`x` in this case is each list of values read from one line, so you want the first one from the list)

Comment: Yep, x[0] and x[:1] and x[0:1] are all the same in that sense: first element, although x[0] will return just the item and x[:1] will return the item as a one-element list (no functional difference here, I believe, unless `.writerows()` complains about wanting a list)